# Matlab read images stored in 4D array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I have been experimenting in Matlab using PCA on different image face databases. I recently acquired several databases from colleague which he acquired years ago. They are .mat files, when I double click the .mat file, the following files are shown

[image]

As you can see the images are stored in this dbface 4D array variable but I am unsure as to how to extract each individual image. I have only been using matlab for few weeks so still getting familiar with it. I have been searching around, but can't find any examples as to how you are meant to extract each individual image from a 4D array.

Any help would be much appreciated

Edit:

```
size(dbface)

ans =
  64    64    11    15

If anyone else encounters this, easiest way to extract is to do the following

%Return rows cols and dimensions
[rows cols dimen1 dimen2] = size(dbface);

count = 0;
%Loop through each image
for i = 1:dimen1
for j = 1:dimen2
count = count + 1;
image = dbface(:,:,i,j);
tmimg=uint8(image); 
img=reshape(tmimg,cols,rows);   
images{count} = img;
end
end
```

Comment: What is the result of `size dbface`? Usually images are not stored in 4D so I think we would need some more information to help you.

Comment: I updated my post. I did not think images would usually be stored in 4D which is why I was confused when I opened the file

Comment: Ask your colleague.  The size and number of classes are clearly on the 3rd and 4th dimensions, but I wouldn't be content to have SO give you the final word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the variables I would guess that you have a lot of 64x64 images.

If this is the case they can be extracted as such

```
myExtract = dbface(:,:,1,1)
```

This will give you the first one, you can vary the last two numbers to extract the other ones.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, can't believe it was that simple. I just need to extract the image using above code, followed by imagesc(myExtract); colormap('gray'), and then I can display the image. Cheers for your help!!